# Running an activity in the background

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that send some details to my db, but when I click the back button it stops.
Is it possible to make it run on the background?I heared that using a Service could solve that issue but since all of my classes are wrriten as Activities I would like to know if it's possible.
It's can't be done with some code on the onStop method?

Comment: No, the onStop should be quick, so you can't keep processing in there. If you have long-running processes, you should put them in the background anyway, but you should also use Activities only for user-interactive processes. Migrating to a `Service` isn't difficult and is wll worth the effort.

Comment: You are looking for the Service. Check out this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Let's assume to my app is some kind of a timer.. I would like to run it in the background but when the user re open it he should see it which is an activity.. how do I split it?What is the service and what is the activity?

Answer (score 2):

Heey,

Create a new class that extends of Service.
Add the necessary overrides.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //this service will run until we stop it
            // This will execute when the service starts


    return START_STICKY; //makes it sticky to keep it on until its destroyd
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
            // when the service is destroyd
}
```

You can start a service with:

```
stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ServiceClassName.class));
```

You can stop a service with:

```
stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ServiceClassName.class));
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that all of your classes are written as Activities, which I am assuming means you have your application logic embedded with your user interface logic.  This is generally not a good practice - you should try and migrate application specific code to a separate class.  By having this functionality outside your user interface, your application will benefit in numerous ways.

To answer your question, it is possible to have your application perform functions in the background by subclassing `Service`.  Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for a great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override the onBackPressed method to do what you want. If you want to "hide" the activity (so the user sees that it 'closes') you can call the [moveTaskToBack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) method.

Comment: The application will keep running after the "moveTaskToBack"?

Comment: You should test the 'background' code that you are using for the db writes. At least it will preserve the state before hiding it.

Comment: And should I use the super.onBackPressed()? I think no since it's the method that killing my app I guess right?

Comment: Yes, do not call super because it will kill your Activity.

Comment: Looks like it's still stoping my activity =\

Comment: Be sure that you are overriding the onBackPressed method. Are you running Android 2.0 at least? Beyond that, we may know the details of how do you constantly write stuff into the db.. are you using async tasks? a big for loop? a sort of listener?

Comment: yes of course,  public void onBackPressed()
    {
     moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should write a Service that the Activity communicates with using intents. Thus it should send the data to the service for it to send to the database, then the service can inform the activity. When the Activity listens to events from the Service, you are implementing the Observer pattern (Listeners in Java and Android and many other event processing systems).

You can also poll the service, but that is not the preferred pattern for getting status updates.